# prove that $\sqrt{4-a^2}+\sqrt{4-b^2}+\sqrt{4-c^2}+(\sqrt{3}-1)(|a-1|+|b-1|+|c-1|)\ge 3\sqrt{3}$ if $a+b+c=3$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

$a,b,c\in[0,2]$
observation

> by triangle inequality $|a|+|b|\ge |a+b| $

$|a-1|+|b-1|+|c-1|\ge |a+b+c-3|$

but $a+b+c=3$

hence

$\sqrt{4-a^2}+\sqrt{4-b^2}+\sqrt{4-c^2}+(\sqrt{3}-1)(|a-1|+|b-1|+|c-1|)\ge \sqrt{4-a^2}+\sqrt{4-b^2}+\sqrt{4-c^2} +0$

hence our question is

$\sqrt{4-a^2}+\sqrt{4-b^2}+\sqrt{4-c^2}\ge 3\sqrt{3}$

wlog we try to prove

> $\sqrt{4-a^2}\ge\sqrt{3}$

$4-a^2\ge 3 \implies a^2-1\le0 $

$a\in \left [-1,1\right ]$ but $a\in [0,2]$ so $a\in [0,1]$

this would mean the inequality works for $a,b,c\in [0,1]$

$a=b=c=1$
but i need to prove it for  $a,b,c\in[0,2]$

for all $  a+b+c=3$

> it is evident that $6=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ac)$

by GM-HM

> $\sqrt{ab}\ge \frac{ab}{a+b}$

so

$\sqrt{4-a^2}=\sqrt{(4-a)(4+a)}\ge\dfrac{16-a^2}{8}$

$\sqrt{4-a^2}+\sqrt{4-b^2}+\sqrt{4-c^2} \ge 6-\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{8}\ge^{AM-GM} 6-3\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}}{8}$

Comment: Concurrently, you try to prove $\sum_{x\in\{a,b,c\}}\sqrt{4-x^2}\ge 3\sqrt{3}$, but this is not true --- e.g., if you choose $a=2$, $b=1$, $c=0$, you have that the LHS is $2+\sqrt{3}$, which is smaller than $3\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: this is contradiction,does that mean this inequality does not hold?
...that it only holds for $a,b,c\in [0,1]$,the question was designed by a student?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to mean this. It means that you maybe shouldn't bound $(\sqrt{3}-1)[...]$ by zero from below, I would think.

Comment: isnt this obvious $|a-1|+|b-1|+|c-1|\ge |a+b+c-3|=|3-3|=0$ by triangle-inequality?

Comment: Well, if you want to show that $5+3\ge 6$, you shouldn't start with $5+3\ge 5+0$.

Comment: i get it,so basically i need a stronger inequality before that,i dont think i have enough tools ...

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm going off now --- maybe you can plot this first to find out if the inequality holds at all

Comment: And by the way, the inequality $|a-1|+|b-1|+|c-1|\ge 0$ you get for free; you don't need the fact that $a+b+c=3$ here. :)

Comment: this has been helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution.

First I would like to emphasize that $a,b,c$ must be non-negative for the inequality to hold. Otherwise a counter-example is $(a,b,c)=(-1,2,2)$.

Thus, we need to prove the following inequality for $0\le a,b,c\le 2$:
$$\sqrt{4-a^2}+\sqrt{4-b^2}+\sqrt{4-c^2}+(\sqrt{3}-1)(|a-1|+|b-1|+|c-1|)\ge 3\sqrt{3}.$$

It suffices to show that the following inequality holds for all $a\in [0,2]$:
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{4-a^2} + (\sqrt{3}-1)|a-1| \ge \sqrt{3} + 1 -a \tag{1}
\end{equation}
(Then similarly we get two other inequalities for $b,c$ and taking the sum of these 3 inequalities we get the result.)

**Proof for $(1)$:**

- If $1\le a\le 2$: $(1)$ becomes
  \begin{align}
  &\sqrt{4-a^2} + (\sqrt{3}-1)(a-1) \ge \sqrt{3} + 1 -a  \\
  \Longleftrightarrow &\sqrt{4-a^2} \ge \sqrt{3}(2-a)\\
   \Longleftrightarrow &4(2-a)(a-1)\ge 0,
  \end{align} which is clearly true.
- If $0\le a< 1$: $(1)$ becomes
  \begin{align}
  &\sqrt{4-a^2} + (\sqrt{3}-1)(1-a) \ge \sqrt{3} + 1 -a  \\
  \Longleftrightarrow &\sqrt{4-a^2} \ge 2-(2-\sqrt{3})a.
  \end{align} 
  Note that the right hand side of the last inequality is positive, squaring the both sides and taking the difference we get the equivalent inequality $4(2-\sqrt{3})a(1-a)\ge 0$, which is clearly true.

Therefore, $(1)$ is proved and the conclusion follows. Equality holds if and only if $(a,b,c)=(1,1,1)$ or a permutation of $(0,1,2)$.

*Remark.* According to the proof, we see that the inequality also holds for the weaker condition $a+b+c\le 3$.

Comment: Separation of variables. Nice. +1.

Comment: thanks @Khue this is a stronger inequality

Comment: No problem, @Jonas12. If my answer resolves your problem, then please accept it. Thanks.